# Can't see a GeoMap Google Vizualization in GWT with gwt-google-apis

Tags: gwt, google-visualization, google-api-java-client

Nothing but an empty div appears. Here's my code for a minimal example. (Similar code to create a PieChart works fine.) Thanks!

```
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.AbstractDataTable.ColumnType;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.DataTable;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.VisualizationUtils;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.visualizations.GeoMap;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.visualizations.GeoMap.Options;

    VisualizationUtils.loadVisualizationApi(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            setup();
        }
    }, GeoMap.PACKAGE);

protected void setup() {
    final Options options = Options.create();
    options.setDataMode(GeoMap.DataMode.MARKERS);
    options.setHeight(300);
    options.setWidth(450);
    options.setShowLegend(false);
    options.setColors(0xFF8747, 0xFFB581, 0xc06000);
    options.setRegion("world");

    final DataTable dataTable = DataTable.create();
    dataTable.addRows(2);
    dataTable.addColumn(ColumnType.STRING, "Country");
    dataTable.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Value");

    dataTable.setValue(0, 0, "France");
    dataTable.setValue(0, 1, 100.0);
    dataTable.setValue(0, 0, "US");
    dataTable.setValue(0, 1, 200.0);

    final GeoMap geo = new GeoMap(dataTable, options);
    myPanel.add(geo);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems that my Firefox was missing a Flash player which is required by GeoMap!